# argparse - how to pass argument from args into function?

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse
from queries import most_common_cities

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A script that does operations with database data and returns values')

parser.add_argument('-c', '--most_common_cities',
                nargs=1,
                type=positive_int,
                help='Specify how many common cities.')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.most_common_cities:
result = most_common_cities(n) # "n" should be an arg passed by user
print(result)
```

How could I pass arguments from CLI to my function arg?
When someone use command:

```
python argp.py --most_common_cities 5
```

It should return 5 most common cities.

Comment: what's the error with your code?

Comment: Did you try `print(args)`?  When debugging it's a good idea to check that `args` variable before trying to use it.  It should give you a clear(er) idea of what the parser did.  In this case is should show `Namespace(most_common_cities=[5])`, a number in a list (because of the nargs).  By the way were is `positive_int` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `nargs=1`, then `args.most_common_cities` will be the actual value passed in.

`nargs=1` wraps it in a list.

```
parser.add_argument('-c', '--most_common_cities',
                type=int,
                help='Specify how many common cities.')

args = parser.parse_args(['-c', '5'])
n = args.most_common_cities
print(n)
print(type(n))
# 5
# <class 'int'>
```

Comment: What to change if my next function need to pass two args?

Comment: @calypso I'm not sure what you mean, but you should probably ask that as another question with all the details.

Answer (score -1):

I started your script with following command:

```
python3 test.py --most_common_cities 5
```

You can access the arguments with:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A script that does operations with database data and returns values')

parser.add_argument('-c', '--most_common_cities',
                nargs=1,
                type=int,
                help='Specify how many common cities.')

args = parser.parse_args()

arguments = vars(parser.parse_args())
print(arguments) #{'most_common_cities': [5]}

#then you can access the value with:
arguments['most_common_cities']
```

Comment: OP is using `argparse` so using `sys.argv` kinda beats the purpose

Comment: i made the change so he doesnt need sys argv

Comment: That still overcomplicates things. No need for `vars`. The arguments are already available on `args`, ie `args.most_common_cities`

Comment: I don't understand it, but I will back to this later. Now I just have to finish my script. Thank you for your help!